# Frontend filters form should be added manually?

Tags: content-filtering, joomla-3.5, jlayout

In my custom components I often use **filters and searchbar** for views based on **JModelList** structure. It's clear for me how to set up model/view params and filters, but I'm not sure of the default.php code to print filters (even if it works).
This is my current code:

```
<form class='filter-form'>
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this)); ?>
</form>
```

Is it correct to add manually a form or is there a Joomla way to do it? Should I add some attributes to the form tag?